# incomprehensible error in android layout, how to detect the problem and solve it?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I build an app and it was working very well by Kotlin Language. After I added some elements in a specific layout, **I found the app doesn't run and I find this error:**
[image: Failed to compile resource file]

[image: Resource compilation failed]

**And this tags layout page:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.albnaapp.empusers.warehouse.AddDepositFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/client_name"
            style="@style/TitleTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/str_client_name"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/client_code"
            style="@style/HintTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="39dp"
            android:hint="@string/str_hint_enterTheCode"
            android:textColorHint="#757575"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/deposit_amount"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/client_name"
            tools:ignore="LabelFor,TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/deposit_amount"
            style="@style/HintTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/str_hint_enterTheAmount"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:textColorHint="#757575"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/client_code"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/client_name"
            tools:ignore="Autofill,LabelFor,SpeakableTextPresentCheck,TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/deposit_type"
            style="@style/NormalStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/Space6_48"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/str_deposit_type"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/client_code" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/details_group"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/deposit_type">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/type_deposit"
                style="@style/NormalStyleLtBlue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="@string/str_deposit" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/type_cheque"
                style="@style/NormalStyleLtBlue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/str_cheque" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/type_receipt"
                style="@style/NormalStyleLtBlue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/str_receipt" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/type_mail"
                style="@style/NormalStyleLtBlue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/str_mail" />

        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/more_details"
            style="@style/NormalStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/Space6_48"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/str_more_details"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/details_group" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/more_group"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/more_details">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/is_for_me"
                style="@style/NormalStyleLtBlue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/str_forMe" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/isn't_for_me"
                style="@style/NormalStyleLtBlue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/str_forOthers" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**Please help me to solve this problem. As I don't know where the problem and I don't know how to solve it. And if you need more details, don't hesitate to tell me.**

Comment: It is hard to follow that without knowing a diff between the working variant and what you added. Could you edit your question and add that as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the apostrophe in the radio button id is an issue.

`android:id="@+id/isn't_for_me"`

is not a valid id.

Go with something like this instead

`android:id="@+id/is_not_for_me"`

Comment: I'm really thankful for you. It has been successfully solved. You're so good attention man 